# Не могу получить управляемый компонент JSF (с @RequestScoped) через HttpServletRequest и RequestMap

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf

Пробую получить JSF Managed Bean `BookController` 3-мя способами (`FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();`):

1. `BookController bk = (BookController) ((HttpServletRequest) ctx.getExternalContext().getRequest()).getAttribute("bookController");`
2. `BookController bk = (BookController) ctx.getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("bookController");`
3. `BookController bk = ctx.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(ctx, "#{bookController}", BookController.class);`

`BookController`

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class BookController {}
```

Получается только с помощью 3-го метода, остальные возвращают `null`. Почему?

Answer (score 0):

В примере приведён CDI бин. CDI бины не охраняться в HTTP параметрах, поэтому первые варианты возвращают null.